# How to call one function at click but on second click (same button) call another function? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I want to click dynamically to call one function and another. This is halfway work, but I need the best way to do this. Check out my code and I'll explain it further.

my html table function:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="country" >
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef (click)="sortingCountryTableAsc() ? sortingCountryTableAsc() : sortingCountryTableDesc()"> Country </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.country}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

my ts file:

```
  sortingCountryTableAsc(){
    this.country.sortCountryAsc().subscribe(data => {
      this.allCountry = data;
      this.CountryDataSource.data = this.allCountry;
    })
  }

  sortingCountryTableDesc() {
    this.country.sortCountryDesc().subscribe(data => {
      this.allCountry = data;
      this.CountryDataSource.data = this.allCountry;
    })
  }
```

Okey onclick function i want to call one function and on another click call second. 
I KNOW I HAVE SORT FUNCTION IN ANGULAR MATERIAL BUT I WAN'T USE IT.

Comment: I suggest call always the same function and use a boolean property to toggle

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question after people have taken the trouble to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="country" >
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef (click)="getDataForSort()">
    <span *ngIf="sortAsc">
      &uarr;
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="!sortAsc">
      &darr;
    </span>
    Country 
  </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.country}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

```
public sortAsc = true;
...
getDataForSort() {
  // filp asc and desc
  this.sortAsc = !this.sortAsc;
  const dataSource$: any;
  if (this.sortAsc) {
    dataSource$ = this.country.sortCountryAsc();
  } else {
    dataSource$ = this.country.sortCountryDesc();
  }
  dataSource$.subscribe(data => {
      this.allCountry = data;
      this.CountryDataSource.data = this.allCountry;
    });
}
```

Comment: Hmm this is work. Very very good.
Can you tell me how to set arrow up down angualr material and that is all. 
Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how to use Angular Material to add the arrows since I have never used Angular Material before but I edited my answer to do arrows using HTML entities (https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/), You can look into their documentation but for me their documentation is tough to read (https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a higher order function that can wrap a boolean flag, and depending on a flag, execute a functionality or another:

```
const toggleFunction = (() => {
  let toggle = true;

  return () => {
   toggle = !toggle;

   console.log(toggle);
  }
})()

toggleFunction()
// false

toggleFunction()
// true
```